# Can't remove DIV from hooks in Storefront child theme

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme

I am creating a child theme using WooCommerce Storefront. I am trying to use hooks as much as possible as I understand this is best practice.

However, even after I have removed all of the actions associated with this hook there is still a DIV remaining:
`<div class="col-full"></div>`

I removed the actions by adding this into my themes functions.php file

```
function remove_default_hooks() {

    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_site_branding',                    20 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation',             30 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper',       42 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation',               50 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close', 68 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 40 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart',    60 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_skip_links',                       0);
    remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar',           999 );

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'remove_default_hooks' );
```

If I remove the hook altogether the DIV disappears. I have searched through all the files both in the WooCommerce plugin and Storefront theme and can't find where this DIV is coming from. It's also not inside `header.php`

The DIV is located inside the `<header>`:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header fixed-top row no-gutters mt-0 pt-0 align-items-center" role="banner" style="">
<div class="col-full">
</div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

This appears like so in `header.php`:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header fixed-top row no-gutters mt-0 pt-0 align-items-center" role="banner" style="<?php storefront_header_styles(); ?>">
<?php
/**
* Functions hooked into storefront_header action
*
* @hooked storefront_skip_links                       - 0
* @hooked storefront_social_icons                     - 10
* @hooked storefront_site_branding                    - 20
* @hooked storefront_secondary_navigation             - 30
* @hooked storefront_product_search                   - 40
* @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper       - 42
* @hooked storefront_primary_navigation               - 50
* @hooked storefront_header_cart                      - 60
* @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close - 68
*/
do_action( 'storefront_header' );    
?>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

I can't find an `add_action` for `storefront_social_icons`.

How do I remove this annoying DIV?

Edit: You can take a look here: [Open Development Page](http://hambletonales.tabby.design)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Storefront version 3.0:***

[Code of the header.php in version 3.0](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/storefront/2.3.0/header.php)

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="<?php storefront_header_styles(); ?>">

    <?php
    /**
     * Functions hooked into storefront_header action
     *
     * @hooked storefront_header_container                 - 0
     * @hooked storefront_skip_links                       - 5
     * @hooked storefront_social_icons                     - 10
     * @hooked storefront_site_branding                    - 20
     * @hooked storefront_secondary_navigation             - 30
     * @hooked storefront_product_search                   - 40
     * @hooked storefront_header_container_close           - 41
     * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper       - 42
     * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation               - 50
     * @hooked storefront_header_cart                      - 60
     * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close - 68
     */
    do_action( 'storefront_header' ); ?>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

In version 3.0 the

```
<div class="col-full">
```

and

```
</div>
```

will be created by the hooks "storefront_header_container" and "storefront_header_container_close". You find the implementation of these two hooks in the file [storefront-template-functions.php](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/storefront/2.3.0/inc/storefront-template-functions.php)

To remove these hooks you can do something like this:

```
function remove_default_hooks() {

remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_container',                   0 );
remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_container_close',                   0 );

}

add_action( 'init', 'remove_default_hooks' );
```

***Storefront version 2.8 and smaller:***

[Code of the header.php in version 2.8](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/storefront/2.2.8/header.php)

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="<?php storefront_header_styles(); ?>">
    <div class="col-full">

        <?php
        /**
         * Functions hooked into storefront_header action
         *
         * @hooked storefront_skip_links                       - 0
         * @hooked storefront_social_icons                     - 10
         * @hooked storefront_site_branding                    - 20
         * @hooked storefront_secondary_navigation             - 30
         * @hooked storefront_product_search                   - 40
         * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper       - 42
         * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation               - 50
         * @hooked storefront_header_cart                      - 60
         * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close - 68
         */
        do_action( 'storefront_header' ); ?>

    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

In version 2.8 and smaller the

```
<div class="col-full">
```

and

```
</div>
```

are part of the header.php file. The only way to remove that two html elements is to overwrite header.php file in your child-template.

Comment: I think either my plugin or template was out of date and some of the actions you listed above did not show up. After updating everything I found the hooks you mentioned and everything went smoothly! Thank you!